# Error message 401 unauthorized if I try to apply a design over a SharePoint Online Teamsite

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, powershell-5.1, runbook

I use a runbook with Powershell 5.1 and the pnp.powershell 1.12 framework.

I create a SharePoint site automatically with a managed identity. Everything works fine untile I try to apply the design which I have created before. I always get the message unauthorized. I don't know where I need to gave the managed identity more rights.

I hope you can help.

here is the code so far:

```
   write-output "Site is not created yet!"
   
   New-PNPSite -Type TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group -Title $siteTitle -url $siteUrl - 
   Owner "matthias@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com" -Lcid 1033

   write-output "The site has been created!"

   write-output "Connect to new site $siteTitle" 

   Connect-PnPOnline -url $siteUrl -ManagedIdentity

   Get-PnPContext

   write-output "Create Folders"
 
  $Folder100= Add-PNPFolder -Name $folderName100 -Folder $relativFolderPath
  $Folder200= Add-PNPFolder -Name $folderName200 -Folder $relativFolderPath
  $Folder300= Add-PNPFolder -Name $folderName300 -Folder $relativFolderPath
  $Folder900= Add-PNPFolder -Name $folderName900 -Folder $relativFolderPath
  


  #site Design
  Add-PnPSiteDesignTask -SiteDesignId eb8c67ca-9342-4821-b0ec-a173cc6481e6
```

then in the last step I get the error message: The remote server returned an error: (401)
Unauthorized.

[error Message runbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UETFn.png)

Answer (score 0):

To implement the design, you must provide the managed identity the necessary privileges. Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity.md) to apply the required permissions to the managed identity.

Make sure that you are connecting to sharepoint in an administrator mode.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com" -clientId <APPID> -clientSecret <appsecret>
```

```
Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site <siteurl> -AppId <ID> -PermissionGroup "read/write"
```

Once you give read/write permissions through  [`Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission`](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html) PowerShell command, use
[`Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission`](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html) to give full control permissions.

The above steps will give the complete permissions to access the share point and implement the site design.

*Note:* Check the `PnP.Powershell` module version. It should be compatible with the PowerShell runtime version of runbook in azure automation(5.1).

[image]

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by my own. I want to use a managed identity and not an app registration.

I changed the last lines to the following:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url "https://tenant-admin.shareppint.com" 
-ManagedIdentity

Add-PnPSiteDesignTask -SiteDesignId eb8c67ca-9342-4821-b0ec-a173cc6481e6 
-weburl "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/name"
```

Then it works without any problems.